# Codeigniter passing data from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter .Can some one please help me by telling how to pass `$row['main_products_cat_id'];` in model to `'id'=> 'my id here',` in controller. I tried so many ways but I failed.

Thanks!!!

**This is my model**

```
function cart_product_records($id){

        $this->db->from('tbl_sub_products');
        $this->db->where('tbl_sub_products.sub_product_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){

            echo $row['main_products_cat_id'];
            echo $row['sub_product_id'];
            echo $row['sub_product_name'];
            echo $row['sub_product_description'];
            echo $row['sub_product_image'];
            echo $row['sub_product_price'];    
        }
        return $query->result();    
}
```

**this is my controller**

```
function shopping_cart(){  

        $id = $this->input->get('id');    
        if($query =   $this->mod_products->cart_product_records($id)){

            $data['result'] = array(

                       'id'      => 'my id here',
                       'qty'     => my qty here,
                       'price'   => my price here,
                       'name'    => 'my product name here'

                    );
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - you should not `echo` data in your model - you should really only `echo` data in your view file.

The way that your data is flowing is first you are passing `$id` from your controller to your `cart_product_records` function in the `mod_products` model.  The model then runs a query and gets data from your database.  This data is represented by `$query->result_array()` or `$query->result()` (you're using both of these but you should only use one, once).

So you then have `return $query->result()` which sends your data back to your controller.  The data will be stored in the `$query` variable, because you have `$query = $this->mod_products->cart_product_records($id)`.

If I were you I would add an `!empty()` check to the if statement, so it would look like this:

```
if( !empty($query =   $this->mod_products->cart_product_records($id)) ){
```

Then, depending on what data you want to get from `$query`, you're either going to want to construct a loop (which would enable you to extract multiple ids, prices, etc), or you could retrieve specific values from `$query`, like `$query[0][main_products_cat_id]` (assuming `$query` is an array) or `$query[0]->main_products_cat_id` (if it's an object).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your *$query* holds the database results object. So, you'll do this in your $data array in your controller.

```
$data['result'] = array(
    'id' => $query->main_products_cat_id,
    // carry on...
);
```

Comment: I think it would be `$query[0]->main_products_cat_id`

Comment: You're right. I would return $query[0] from the model.

Answer (score 1):

I dosen't make any sense to write

```
echo $row['main_products_cat_id'];
....
```

In your loop create array as

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){

           $return_array[] = $row;
        }
        return $return_array
```

and in controller, you can access as

```
$query['your_id'];
```